# How to get the list of the names of ID(children) from a class(parent)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

The source code of a website has a div class with multiple ids within it. How do I get the value of id's alone by referencing the class name using javascript? [Check this for the source code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0suy.png)

Comment: You can do this: `const ids = [...document.body.querySelector('.d2VDTCtr').querySelectorAll('[id]')].map(e => e.id);`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It worked. You helped me at the right time. But, I need only the ID's. It shows me the ID names with KPI too. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: What do you mean by **KPI** ? The code above looks for all the elements that have an `id` attribute inside the element with class `d2VDTCtr` and then gets the value of that `id` attribute.